# Can't boot CD to install Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 9.04 on my PC. I have Windows XP installed as a primary OS. After booting from Ubuntu CD, it halts at the following screen and it never occurred before while I installed it.

```
Busybox v1.10.2 (Ubuntu
1:1.10.2-2ubuntu7) built-in shell(ash)

Enter help for a list of built-in commands. 

(initramfs)_
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to run the "Check for defects" option on the first CD screen. Maybe the CD is faulty?

Answer (score 0):

One reason that happens is if your root partition is unbootable for some reason.

Try the following:

(1) Boot from the Ubuntu Live CD if possible, or another Linux Live CD and try to mount the root partition on your hard drive manually.  See if there are any errors.

> sudo mkdir /media/try
>
> sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/try

(substituting your root partition number for 'sda1'

(2) Try delaying the boot, so that any modules necessary to boot your drive are sure to be loaded before it tries to mount:

(a) wait a few seconds after the busy box prompt appears.  Type exit.  The boot may continue.

(b) for a more permanant solution, add a bootdelay=[somenumber] to the bootline in grub.

Deails for both of these [here](http://samiux.wordpress.com/2008/12/16/howto-avoid-to-drop-to-busybox-in-ubuntu-810/)

(3) Of course you can also try installing Ubuntu 9.10 instead (released 2 weeks ago), to see if whatever hardware quirk you're experiencing has been found and addressed.